# joomla-extracting a component as installable?

Tags: joomla, components, joomla-extensions, custom-component, extract

I am writing a joomla componenet but it has many folders and sql tables. I don't prefere to make the package manually. Is there any know extension to make me able to extract my component as a zip file to make it installable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm so confused. Why would you need an extension to compile your component? By the sounds of thing, you have simply started editing a pre-made component.

You should have started with the folder and file stricture when you first started building the component.

Create 2 folders:

1. admin
2. site

Put all backend end related folder inside the **admin** folder, and all frontend related folders inside the **site** folder.

Then edit your XML file accordingly to it points to the correct folders

Comment: I can do that ofcourse but just I want to know if ther is an app to to do it for me. Sql statements/tables are confusing me. İf there is no such app I will accept your answer. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: There isn't an extension for this. There are component generators but these generate the files and folder for you before you start, not after.

Answer (score 0):

There is a third-party component: http://joomlatoys.com/index.php/toys/jtbuilder which can package the selected extensions and generate an installable archive for you.